# How to use conditional statement to map duplicates first and last with multiple columns in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with the following dataframe:

```
  issue_status   market_phase   trading_status   is_and_mp      market_state         reason
0     10              0             B0              100       UNSCHEDULED_AUCTION
1     20              0                             200       CONTINUOUS_TRADING
2     40              0             D1              400           POST_TRADE
3     10              0                             100           
4     10              0                             100  
5     40              0                             400
6     40              0                             400
7     40              0                             400
```

I am trying to write a Python condition where if `is_and_mp` is `100` and `trading_status` is `None`, then for the first instance of `is_and_mp` of 100, mark an `F` in the `reason` column.

And do the same if `is_and_mp` is 400 and `trading_status` is `None`.
For the second last instance where `is_and_mp` is `400` and `trading_status` is None, mark an `SL` in the `reason` column.
Finally for the last instance where `is_and_mp` is `400` and `trading_status` is `None`, mark `L` in the `reason` column.

So the above dataframe should look like this:

```
  issue_status   market_phase   trading_status   is_and_mp      market_state         reason
0     10              0             B0              100       UNSCHEDULED_AUCTION
1     20              0                             200       CONTINUOUS_TRADING
2     40              0             D1              400           POST_TRADE
3     10              0                             100                                F
4     10              0                             100  
5     40              0                             400                                 
6     40              0                             400                                SL
7     40              0                             400                                L
```

The logic for `100` and `400` doesn't have to be together, it can be separated if it is easier!

@Azhar thank you for your solution, I tried it for the following input but it doesn't quite do the desired mapping- could you kindly advise?:

```
          trading_status is_and_mp         market_state        groups
0                           000               CLOSED              1  
1                           200       CONTINUOUS_TRADING          2  
2                           103                 None              3  
3                           204     UNSCHEDULED_AUCTION           4  
4                           203     UNSCHEDULED_AUCTION           5  
5                B0         100     UNSCHEDULED_AUCTION           6  
6                B1         200      CONTINUOUS_TRADING           7  
7                           400                 None              8  
8                A0         400               HALTED              9  
9                           100                 None             10  
10                          100                 None             10  
11                          400                 None             11                    
12                          400                 None            12
```

expected output for group` column:

```
        groups 
  0       1
  1       2
  2       3
  3       4
  4       5
  5       6
  6       7
  7       8
  8       9
  9       10 
 10       10
 11       8
 12       8
```

Comment: Your logic has conflicts. For example, last 3 rows where "is_and_mp" is 400, and status is None, you have selected different reasons as F, SL and L. This is not clear.

Comment: What do you mean when you say there is a conflict? Each is mapped to something different right? Depending on when it comes first or last or inbetween

Comment: So we could have 100 lines of `is_and_mp` == `400` and status == `None`. in this case, the first row would have `F` in reason, all the others would have `None` or nothing, the second last row (99th row) would have `SL` and the last row (100th row) would have `L` in the reason column. If this makes sense?

Comment: Please let me know if it doesn't make sense, this is the last part would really appreciat eyour help!

Comment: Ok, it is clear now; but why 100 on line #4 does not have reason L, when line #3 has F?

Comment: What is the expected output with new input?

Comment: Good point, but yes that is correct, line #4 should not have reason L, it is just the way the mapping is! Only on the 400 it should have an L for the last appearance! :)

Comment: Let me add the expected output now

Comment: So it is just rows 11 and 12 that are being mapped wrongly!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249776/discussion-between-azhar-khan-and-patrick-chong).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Following answer is updated after @PatrickChong 's updated logic:

```py
# df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[None,"000","CLOSED"],[None,"200","CONTINUOUS_TRADING"],[None,"103","None"],[None,"204","UNSCHEDULED_AUCTION"],[None,"203","UNSCHEDULED_AUCTION"],["B0","100","UNSCHEDULED_AUCTION"],["B1","200","CONTINUOUS_TRADING"],[None,"400","None"],["A0","400","HALTED"],[None,"100","None"],[None,"100","None"],[None,"400","None"],[None,"400","None"]], columns=["trading_status","is_and_mp","market_state"])
# df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[10,0,"B0","100","UNSCHEDULED_AUCTION"],[20,0,None,"200","CONTINUOUS_TRADING"],[40,0,"D1","400","POST_TRADE"],[10,0,None,"100",""],[10,0,None,"100",""],[40,0,None,"400",""],[40,0,None,"400",""],[40,0,None,"400",""]], columns=["issue_status","market_phase","trading_status","is_and_mp","market_state"])
# df = pd.DataFrame(data=[["100","A0"],["100",None],["400",None],["100",None],["400",None],["100",'B2'],["400",None],["100",None],["400","A6"]], columns=["is_and_mp","trading_status"])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[["400",None],["100","A0"],["400",None],["400","A0"],["100",None],["100",None]], columns=["is_and_mp","trading_status"])

df["tmp"] = list(zip(df.is_and_mp, df.trading_status))
df["reason"] = df.groupby(["is_and_mp", df.trading_status.astype(str)])["tmp"].transform(lambda grp: ["F" if v[0]=="100" and v[1]==None and i==0 else "SL" if v[0]=="400" and v[1]==None and len(grp)>1 and i==len(grp)-2 else "L" if v[0]=="400" and v[1]==None and len(grp)>1 and i==len(grp)-1 else "" for i,v in enumerate(grp)])
df = df.drop("tmp", axis=1)

[Out]:
  is_and_mp trading_status reason
0       400           None     SL
1       100             A0       
2       400           None      L
3       400             A0       
4       100           None      F
5       100           None
```

Another [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74518334/how-can-i-use-python-conditionals-to-map-columns-in-a-dataframe-with-duplicates)

---

Create a "group" column to represent similar group of records which match the given condition:

```py
df["group"] = (~((df["is_and_mp"].eq(df["is_and_mp"].shift())) & (df["trading_status"] == ""))).cumsum()
```

Then create the output "reason" column by matching the required logic:

```py
df["reason"] = df.groupby("group")["is_and_mp"].transform(lambda grp: ["F" if v=="100" and len(grp)>1 and i==0 else "SL" if v=="400" and len(grp)>1 and i==len(grp)-2 else "L" if v=="400" and len(grp)>1 and i==len(grp)-1 else "" for i,v in enumerate(grp)])
```

Full example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[10,0,"B0","100","UNSCHEDULED_AUCTION"],[20,0,"","200","CONTINUOUS_TRADING"],[40,0,"D1","400","POST_TRADE"],[10,0,"","100",""],[10,0,"","100",""],[40,0,"","400",""],[40,0,"","400",""],[40,0,"","400",""]], columns=["issue_status","market_phase","trading_status","is_and_mp","market_state"])

df["group"] = (~((df["is_and_mp"].eq(df["is_and_mp"].shift())) & (df["trading_status"] == ""))).cumsum()

df["reason"] = df.groupby("group")["is_and_mp"].transform(lambda grp: ["F" if v=="100" and len(grp)>1 and i==0 else "SL" if v=="400" and len(grp)>1 and i==len(grp)-2 else "L" if v=="400" and len(grp)>1 and i==len(grp)-1 else "" for i,v in enumerate(grp)])

[Out]:
   issue_status  market_phase trading_status is_and_mp         market_state  group reason
0            10             0             B0       100  UNSCHEDULED_AUCTION      1       
1            20             0                      200   CONTINUOUS_TRADING      2       
2            40             0             D1       400           POST_TRADE      3       
3            10             0                      100                           4      F
4            10             0                      100                           4       
5            40             0                      400                           5       
6            40             0                      400                           5     SL
7            40             0                      400                           5      L
```

Comment: Thank you so much Azhar!, Could you kindly take a look at the above example that I included? The code for `groups` column doesn't quite produce the desired result.

Comment: @PatrickChong, I have updated answer as per your updated logic. Hope this works. Your earlier dataset gave impression that you needed a series (i.e. 400 to appear next to each other), hence it was complicated with `shift()` et al. In the updated answer I have used all your past datasets and verified the results. Let me know if it works for you.