# How can I use python conditionals to map columns in a dataframe with duplicates in them?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a mapping where there are duplicates in certain columns in a dataframe.

Here are two examples of dataframes I am working with:

```
issue_status        trading_state         reason
    100                  'A0'                
    100                  None               'F'
    400                  None
    100                  None
    400                  None               'SL'
    100                  'B2'
    400                  None               'L'
    100                  None 
    400                  'A6'
```

Here is what I need;  3 conditional python logic that does:

- when we see the first `issue_status` of `100` and `trading_state` of None, map `F` in the `reason` column.
- when we see the second last `issue_status` of `400` and `trading_state` of None, map `SL` in the `reason` column.
- when we see the last `issue_status` of `400` and `trading_state` of None, map `L` in the `reason` column.

Here is another example:

```
 issue_status      trading_state      reason
     400                None            'SL'
     100                'A0'
     400                None            'L'
     400                'A0'
     100                None            'F'
     100                None
```

@jezrael, I am getting the following error, for your last line of code
(`market_info_df1['reason'] = s1.combine_first(s2)`):

```
@wraps(func)
    def outer(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
        except NormalisedDataError:
            raise
        except Exception as exc:
            original = exc.__class__.__name__
>           raise NormalisedDataError(f'{original}: {exc}', original_exception_type=original) from exc
SettingWithCopyError: 
E           A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
E           Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
E           
E           See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
```

Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: The last two conditions are equal, but the result is wanted to be different! Do you really mean that?

Comment: yes please- if by conditions you mean the `issue_status` of 400 and `trading_state` is `None`, then yes :) 

The reason is that in my dataset I have multiple dataframes each with a different number of rows. And I want to identify in the above case, the last row 'L' when `issue_status` is 400 and `trading_state` is `None`. And also the second last row 'SL' when we see`issue_status` is 400 and `trading_state` is `None`

Comment: Any ideas how it can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter by `400` and `None` values for `df1`, create helper `Series` with `range` and mapping last and second last values, for first `100` and `None` values use [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html), last join both `Series` by [`Series.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
#if None is string
#m1 = df['trading_state'].eq('None')
m1 = df['trading_state'].isna()

m2 = df['issue_status'].eq(400)
m3 = df['issue_status'].eq(100)

df1 = df[m1 & m2].copy()

s1 = pd.Series(range(len(df1), 0, -1), index=df1.index).map({1:'L', 2:'SL'})
s2 = df.loc[m1 & m3, 'issue_status'].copy().duplicated().map({False:'F'})

df['reason'] = s1.combine_first(s2)
print (df)
   issue_status trading_state reason
0           100          'A0'    NaN
1           100          None      F
2           400          None    NaN
3           100          None    NaN
4           400          None     SL
5           100          'B2'    NaN
6           400          None      L
7           100          None    NaN
8           400          'A6'    NaN
```

For second:

```
df['reason'] = s1.combine_first(s2)
print (df)
   issue_status trading_state reason
0           400          None     SL
1           100          'A0'    NaN
2           400          None      L
3           400          'A0'    NaN
4           100          None      F
5           100          None    NaN
```

If necessary empty strings in `reason` column use:

```
df['reason'] = df['reason'].fillna('')
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrawl for the answer. 

I am getting an error when I run the code. Could you kindly see the question- I have added the error log there.

Comment: @PatrickChong - Maybe problem is with filtering, can you add `.copy()` like in [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74518975/revisions) answer?

Comment: You are a magician my friend! Thank you very much.

Comment: I have a small follow-up if you have a minute https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74519937/how-can-i-update-an-existing-dataframe-to-add-values-without-overwriting-other. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @PatrickChong - answer was created.