# How can I overwrite a mapping of a column based on its current value and value of two other columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframe

```
is_and_mp    market_state       reason     
  '100'          None             NaN  
  '400'          None             NaN 
  '100'          ALGO             NaN
  '400'          OPENING          NaN
```

I want to write two mappings where if `is_and_mp` is either `'100'` or `'400'`, and `market_state == None` and `reason == NaN`, then map `market_state =CONTINUOUS_TRADING`.

So the output would be:

```
is_and_mp         market_state              reason     
  '100'        CONTINUOUS_TRADING             NaN  
  '400'        CONTINUOUS_TRADING             NaN
  '100'             ALGO                      NaN
  '400'           OPENING                     NaN
```

It is important for the existing mappings not to change! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with chained mask by `&` for bitwise `AND`:

```
df.loc[df.is_and_mp.isin([ '100', '400']) & df.market_state.isna() & df. reason.isna(),  'market_stat'] = 'CONTINUOUS_TRADING'
```

or if values are numeric:

```
df.loc[df.is_and_mp.isin([ 100, 400]) & df.market_state.isna() & df. reason.isna(),  'market_stat'] = 'CONTINUOUS_TRADING'
```

Comment: You are a king @jezrael, I learned so much today. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using `&` in complex query in `df.loc` should be inside parenthesis `()`

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "is_and_mp": ['100', '400', '100', '400'],
    "market_state": [None, None, 'ALGO', 'OPENING'],
    "reason": ['NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.loc[(df["is_and_mp"].isin(['100', '400'])) & (df["market_state"].isna()) & (df["reason"] == 'NaN'), "market_state"] = "CONTINUOUS_TRADING"
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  is_and_mp        market_state reason
0       100  CONTINUOUS_TRADING    NaN
1       400  CONTINUOUS_TRADING    NaN
2       100                ALGO    NaN
3       400             OPENING    NaN
```